# Creating html content/element dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, onblur, createelement

I'm trying to build a login page.  When you tab out of the first text box (the username) I would like the page to display some information based on the text entered, before the password is entered.  Right now, I'm having trouble just getting anything to show up using the onblur event.  Here is what I have so far.

```
<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
function createDiv()
{
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.style.position = "absolute";
divTag.style.top = "150px";
divTag.style.left = "450px";
divTag.style.zIndex = "20";
divTag.innerHTML = "This is information";
document.getElementByID('card').appendChild(divTag);
}
</script>

<body onload='init();'>
<div id="card" style="width:800px; z-index:10; height:600px; position:relative; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; margin-top:0px; background-image:url('customLoginBG.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<form method='post' action='/login'>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li> <input type='hidden' id='token' name='token' /> </li>
<li style="position:absolute; top:270px; left:260px;"> <input type='text' onblur="createDiv()" id='username' style="width:188px; height:27px; background-image:url('inputBar.png');" /> </li>
<li style="position:absolute; top:310px; left:260px;"> <input type='password' id='password' style="width:188px; height:27px; background-image:url('inputBar.png');" /> </li>
<li style="position:absolute; top:290px; left:455px;"> <input type='image' src="loginButton.png" value="Login" onclick='doLogin();' /> </li>          
</ul>  
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Any thoughts and/or suggestions?  Just getting anything to display onblur would be a good start.

Comment: Where is this onblur event in your code? P.s. learn to use style sheets rather than inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

It's `document.getElementById()` not `document.getElementByID()`

In your case:

```
// doesn't work
document.getElementByID('card').appendChild(divTag);
// works as expected
document.getElementById('card').appendChild(divTag);
```

Answer (score -5):

One suggestion, (more of a question actually) : why vanilla js and not jquery or any other productivity library ?